Does ... (triple dot) exists in file paths?
I'm aware of the significance and use of . and .. in file paths (explained here) But I question a path starting with triple dot ... as in
...\path\to\my\file.txt
Why do I ask> - getting playlists to work properly without a specific drive letter the format seems to be in the form
...\Music\The Beatles\Hey Jude.mp3
...\Music\The Beatles\Lucy In The Sky With Diamonds.mp3

I suspect this is a formatting issue, but would like to ask the elders.

Is it possible that the ellipsis in the context you're working on just represents the normal meaning of an ellipsis, i.e. "There is an omission here" rather than literal syntax? I don't think it's uncommon to see something along the lines of ".../Program/file.txt" to just mean "We don't know where you store your program data for Program so fill this in yourself."

I may me taking things literally, i have a tendency to do that.

It would help if you told what "playlists" you're talking about. The link in the question goes nowhere.

I would edit it, to correct it... but it looks like others want it deleted.


In POSIX systems (such as Linux, UNIX, or MacOS), the ... (three dots) does not have any special meaning as a directory name. Unlike . (current directory) and .. (parent directory), ... is just a normal directory name without any special function in navigation or filesystem operations.  (of course, nevertheless the name is deeply confusing and I would recommend never using it)

In Modern Windows (e.g. Windows 11), I just tried and cd ... and cd ...., etc., have no effect, having the same semantics as the no-op command rem.

For pre-NT Windows versions, see this answer:



Old timer trivia: on Win9x systems (but not NT-based systems), the cd command would treat

... similarly to ..\.. and
.... similarly to ..\..\..,

and so on, at least for the cd command (I don't think it worked like that in general).
I wish this carried over to NT - it was a handy shortcut.

